# 2 разных скрипта при кликах по ячейке

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, можно ли сделать, чтобы выполнялись разные скрипты при первом и повторном кликах по ячейке?
http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/7/ - здесь скрипт.
Нужно, чтобы при первом клике по ячейке она закрашивалась красным (работает), а также данные передавались обработчику, который будет заносить их в БД.
А при поторном клике по закрашенной ячейке она становилась снова белая (работает) и данные передавались второму скрипту, который будет удалять запись из БД с такими данными.
Сейчас работает один и тот же скрипт вне зависимости от того, какой это клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте проверку наличия класса click и в зависимости от его наличия/отсутствия меняйте урл обработчика, остальные данные ведь идентичны :-)

Или же в обработчике проверяйте наличие этой записи и по необходимости добавляйте/удаляйте ее

Comment: Вот такая проверка подойдет:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `dates` = '$dates' AND `uid` = '$uid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    //Скрипт удаления записи
}

else {
    // Скрипт добавления записи
}

Comment: Ну а почему нет? Вы пытались найти в базе подобную запись, если их нашлось ровно 0 - значит добавим, если больше - удалим.

Другой вопрос в том, что это дополнительный запрос…  
Хотя, с другой стороны, полагаться только на данные пользователя тоже не стоит, и в любом случае эта проверка необходима.

Comment: Я бы все-таки сделал выбор действия (добавление/удаление) в скрипте на стороне пользователя, можно даже не урл менять а добавить к данным (uid, dates) еще одну переменную (var action=0; //del var action=1; // add), а в обработчике при удалении просто пытаемся удалить, при добавлении сразу проверим, нет ли такой записи уже, а лишь потом добавим.

Кстати, можно Ваше поле, которое (AI), которое по факту и не нужно, можно было бы заменить на уникальный varchar или int, в котором записывать uid+dates, таким образом исключается возможность создания дубликатов и необходимость дополнительной проверки

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так)))

```
if($(this).hasClass("click")){
        your_url = 'send2.php';
    }
 alert(your_url)
```

Вроде проапдейтил код http://jsfiddle.net/N2EGr/8/